# Calendar in date and time is always in lock state in Mac , how to unlock for always and used it like windows calender

Tags: macos, mac, date-time

Calendar in date and time is always in lock state in Mac , how to unlock and used it like windows calendar

Currently I need to unlock it each time to access calendar

the main intention here is to access calendar dates quickly like we do in windows, here if I need to check another month date then either I need to unlock it or open calendar app separately

[image]

Any way around will be helpful !!!!

Comment: What do you actually want to use that calendar for? Its only purpose is to set the computer to the correct date. System prefs will always admin lock after a few minutes, as a security feature. There's a rather convoluted set of terminal commands you can use to unlock certain prefs for certain users, far to much to précis in an answer - https://blog.macsales.com/41050-how-to-grant-administrative-access-to-locked-preference-panes-for-any-user/

Comment: the main intention here is to access calander dates quickly like we do in windows, here if I need to check another month date then either I need to unlock it or open calander app separately

Comment: "check another month date" ?? Check it for what? The sole purpose of that mini calendar is to change the computer's date & time. It's not a general reference or diary tool. There's a dedicated Calendar app for that, far quicker to get to; or there's a Calendar widget in Dashboard [up to Mojave].

Comment: ya ... actually one of my job component is planning which need sometime quick access of dates of further month/year date .. I got it I need to install some third party app or calendar app itself. .. I raised this question as in windows calender in task bar is not locked like in mac

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the built-in Calendar. Just leave it running all the time. I do. It can sync to iCloud, other users, subscribed calendars, Google calendars, Exchange calendars… What more could you need? You're trying to re-purpose a tool behind a security setting as a general tool it was never meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I understand you, the built-in calendar isn't the most convenient thing. Check this out https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/?utm_source=zapier.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zapier